# Active Admin Rails generating CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have one problem with CSV files generated in active admin in rails. I use default link to download csv and set admin like:

```
csv do
    column :profile_name
    column :account_number
    column :title
    column :amount
    column :status

end
```

But in first row on generated file there are model columns name - how can i remove it?

Comment: That's how CSV works. There might be some way to remove it, but you shouldn't be trying to remove it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override csv template 
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.csv.erb

so copy this file to

> /app/views/active_admin/resource/index.csv.erb

and try to  remove this line https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.csv.erb#L9

```
 csv << columns.map(&:name)
```

so your template should look like

```
<%-
  require 'csv'

  default = active_admin_application.csv_options
  options = default.merge active_admin_config.csv_builder.options
  columns = active_admin_config.csv_builder.columns

  csv_output = CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    collection.each do |resource|
      csv << columns.map do |column|
        call_method_or_proc_on resource, column.data
      end
    end
  end
%>
<%= csv_output.html_safe %>
```